# SONAR is failing to process the submitted data

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

We have a Jenkins job that builds our master project and as a post-step invokes top level Maven targets (Maven version - maven-3.0.4) and goals set to sonar:sonar to Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment.

We also have below properties defined:

> sonar.projectVersion=$BUILD_NUMBER
>
> sonar.projectName=[projectName]
>
> sonar.analysis.mode=publish

We do get a successful build and the job submits data to Sonar, but Sonar’s processing task is reporting as FAILED.

This is the status it reports

```
{
  "task": {
    "id": "AWFONZ84DcBh9CaPJb9r",
    "type": "REPORT",
    "componentId": "AVXYzChzbzALmEi_QDhe",
    "componentKey": "com.xxxxx.xxx:<parent project>",
    "componentName": "<componentName>",
    "componentQualifier": "TRK",
    "status": "FAILED",
    "submittedAt": "2018-01-31T21:53:12+0000",
    "submitterLogin": "admin",
    "startedAt": "2018-01-31T21:53:13+0000",
    "executedAt": "2018-01-31T21:53:14+0000",
    "executionTimeMs": 951,
    "logs": true
  }
}
```

The console logs looks like this:

> [INFO] Analysis report generated in 2041ms, dir size=11 MB
>
> [INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 2366ms, zip size=4 MB
>
> [INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 309ms
>
> [INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse
>
> http://sonarhost:port/dashboard/index/class:projectName
>
> [INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
>
> [INFO] More about the report processing at http://sonarhost:port/api/ce/task?id=AWFXJI2tDcBh9CaPJiMR

Due to this the analysisId doesn't show up in the report and hence, the Unit test code coverage tab in Sonar doesn't get populated with data. Has anyone seen this behavior before? Appreciate the insight anyone can provide.

Comment: What shows up in `$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/ce.log`?

Comment: I see a bunch of log files under `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/ce/logs/REPORT/[analysisId]/[logfile]`